# Laravel : Countries with Laravel Analytics

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

I'm using [Laravel Analytics](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics) to get data of the visitors of my application.
In my **Google Analytics** dashboard, every page have it own visits numbers, unique visitors, countries of visitors etc .. like in this image :

[image]

In my `web.php`, I'm creating a route to test the package :

```
Route::get('/data', function () {
    $analyticsData = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(Period::days(7));
    dd($analyticsData);
});
```

This route returns :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1564 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "url" => "/new"
      "pageTitle" => "test"
      "pageViews" => 1534
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "url" => "/"
      "pageTitle" => "test"
      "pageViews" => 450
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "url" => "/customize/8"
      "pageTitle" => "test"
      "pageViews" => 196
    ]
```

As you can see the returned array have only `url`, `pageTitle` and `pageViews`. **How can I add additional informations in the returned array such as countries or geographic localisation as shown in the first image ?**

Comment: I've never used this package, but it's designed this way in the [source code](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Analytics.php#L63) or [docs](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Analytics.php#L63). It's only supposed to return that data.

Comment: @JustCarty By default, yes. It supposed to return that data. But there is no way I can fetch countries of my visitors ? I used https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker too but that package was a little hard.

Comment: In the docs it states you can perform any query you want: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#all-other-google-analytics-queries Plus corresponding Google Analytics docs: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#all-other-google-analytics-queries

Comment: @JustCarty You are right ! So I think something like `dimensions=ga:country` will do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the package, but reading the docs, something like this will do.
The [package docs](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#all-other-google-analytics-queries) state you can use any query you want, and the [Google Analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries#sessions-by-country) give an example of getting session by location.

```php
public function myCustomMethod($maxResults = 20)
{
    $response = $this->performQuery(
        $period,
        'ga:sessions', // metrics
        [
            'dimensions' => 'ga:country',
            'sort' => '-ga:sessions',
            'max-results' => $maxResults,
        ],
    );

    return collect($response['rows'] ?? [])->map(fn (array $pageRow) => [
        // Do something with the rows that are returned.
        // I'm not sure how they're returned from the main response.
    ]);
}
```

Note, this is completely untested, you might want to fiddle with some of the data here.

Assuming I understand the documentation, this will get all countries (`dimensions`), it will use sessions (`ga:sessions` from second parameter) to measure the countries data.
It'll then just sort and get a maximum number of results.

You could change the metrics to `ga:pageviews`, but it's ultimately down to you what queries you want to use.
I've linked the documentation so you can find them out yourself.

Comment: I performed directly this query on my route     `$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(Period::years(1),
'ga:sessions',['metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews','dimensions' => 'ga:country']);dd($analyticsData); `  And I actually had the countries of ALL pages.

Comment: I'm trying to get the countries for each individual page. To test your code should I create a new controller or modify and existing one ?

Comment: @AlyaKra Never modify package code. It'll get replaced when you `composer update`. Instead create a custom class that extends whatever `$this` is.

Comment: It didn't work. But I have a good idea about how things are working. I will try to get it to work. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @AlyaKra As I said, I've never used the package, this is just a starting point for you. All you need to change are the `// metric` part and the `'dimensions'` part. Just find the perfect query for what you want. Please read the documentation from Google, once you understand that, you can start making more methods for additional queries you might want.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had a problem in what to change first and I didn't notice the google documentation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **spatie/laravel-analytics** package.
As you can see here: [spatie laravel analytics - Analytics.php](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Analytics.php) the fetchMostVisitedPages method that you are calling only returns that data.

Please take a look in github to see more information about this package.

**fetchMostVisitedPages** method:

```
 public function fetchMostVisitedPages(Period $period, int $maxResults = 20): Collection
    {
        $response = $this->performQuery(
            $period,
            'ga:pageviews',
            [
                'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath,ga:pageTitle',
                'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
                'max-results' => $maxResults,
            ],
        );

        return collect($response['rows'] ?? [])->map(fn (array $pageRow) => [
            'url' => $pageRow[0],
            'pageTitle' => $pageRow[1],
            'pageViews' => (int) $pageRow[2],
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: So I'm supposing something like `'Countries' => (int) $pageRow[3],` ? But then again I'm skeptical because it was integrated by default in the package.

Comment: I just found out about custom queries `dimensions=ga:country`. I guess something like this.

Comment: Don't change the default package. You can override the method or following @JustCarty suggestion.  I think you should go with JustCarty suggestion doing the custom query

Comment: This is what I will go by. I managed to output the countries but for all pages. I'm trying to fetch it now for each individual page. Thank you.

Comment: Inside vendor/spatie folder you will have another folder with the package name.